# Using isin with NaN in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
    t2   t5
0  NaN  2.0
1  2.0  NaN
2  3.0  1.0
```

Now I want to check if elements in `t2` is in `t5`, ignoring `NaN`.

Therefore, I run the following code:

```
df['t2'].isin(df['t5'])
```

Which gives:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
```

However, since `NaN!=NaN`, I expected

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
```

How do I get what I expected? And why does this behave this way?

Comment: `isin` relies on hash tables, at least for the small input case, and `np.nan` hashes are comparable and equal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't so much a bug as it is an inconsistency of behavior between similar libraries.  Your columns have a dtype of `float64`, and both Pandas and Numpy have their own ideas of whether or not `nan` is comparable to `nan`<sup>[1]</sup>.  You can see this behavior with `unique`

```
>>> np.unique([np.nan, np.nan])
array([nan, nan])

>>> pd.unique([np.nan, np.nan])
array([nan])
```

So clearly, `pandas` detects some sort of similarity with `nan`, which is the behavior you are seeing with `isin`.

Now for large Series, you *won't* see this behavior<sup>[2]</sup>.  I think I read somewhere that the cutoff is around 10e6, but don't take my word for it.

```
u = pd.Series(np.full(100000000, np.nan, dtype=np.float64))

>>> u.isin(u).any()
False
```

<sub>[1] For large Series (> 10e6), `pandas` uses `numpy`'s definition of `nan`</sub>

<sub>[2] As @root points out, this is `dtype` dependent.</sub>

Comment: TDL for the 10e6 staff :-)

Comment: The large input case is still dtype dependent, e.g. `pd.Series(np.nan, index=range(10**6 + 1), dtype=object)` and `pd.Series(np.nan, index=range(10**6 + 1), dtype='float64')` behave differently

Comment: @root hmm, that's neat!  I still haven't had any luck finding anything backing up *why* the cutoff is there for some dtypes.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `np.nan` is indeed in `[np.nan]`. That is to say `in` is equivalent to say `np.any([a is b for b in lst])`. To get what you want, you can filter out the `NaN`in `df['t2']` first:

```
df['t2'].notna() & df['t2'].isin(df['t5'])
```

gives:

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: t2, dtype: bool
```

Comment: @user3483203 The difference appears in `exec` as well. `np.nan==np.nan` evaluates to `False`, but `np.nan in [np.nan]` evaluates to `True`

Comment: @G.Anderson You're correct, what I should have said is that the example he provided of `np.nan in [np.nan]` isn't really related to the behavior that is showing up here.